# Django rendering display name of choice field in form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, jinja2

tl;dr: How do I make a form output the ‘nice’ name of the choices in a model?

I have a Django model with choices, defined like this:

```
class City(models.Model):
    AMSTERDAM = 'AMS'
    ROTTERDAM = 'ROT'
    THE_HAGUE = 'THE'
    UTRECHT = 'UTR'
    CITY_CHOICES = (
        (AMSTERDAM, 'Amsterdam'),
        (ROTTERDAM, 'Rotterdam'),
        (THE_HAGUE, 'The Hague'),
        (UTRECHT, 'Utrecht'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=CITY_CHOICES,
        default=AMSTERDAM,
        blank=False,
    )
```

In forms.py, the widgets are defined like this:

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'categories', 'city']
        widgets = {'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Enter a descriptive title'}),
            'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'The article'}),
            'categories': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
            'city': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

The form itself is rendered manually (although the same effect happens with just `{{form}}`:

```
<form action="{% url 'article-submit' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{% for field in form %}
        <fieldset class="article-form__field">
        {% if field.name = "categories"%}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            <ul id={{ field.auto_id }}>
            {% for checkbox in field %}
                <li>
                    <label for="{{ checkbox.id_for_label }}">
                        {{ checkbox.choice_label }}
                    </label>
                    {{ checkbox.tag }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% elif field.name = "city" %}
            {{ field.label_tag }}
            <ul id={{ field.auto_id }}>
            {% for radio in field %}
                <li>
                    <label for="{{ radio.id_for_label }}">
                        {{ radio.choice_label }}
                    </label>
                    {{ radio.tag }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
        {% endif %}
        </fieldset>
    {% endfor %}}
    <fieldset class="article-form__field">
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

However the output is not Amsterdam, but AMS:

```
        <fieldset class="article-form__field">

            <label for="city_0">City:</label>
            <ul id=city>

                <li>
                    <label for="city_0">
                        ---------
                    </label>
                    <input checked="checked" id="city_0" name="city" type="radio" value="" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="city_1">
                        AMS
                    </label>
                    <input id="city_1" name="city" type="radio" value="1" />
                </li>
etc.
```

In other templates, I could do this: `{{city.get_name_display}}`, to get the full name. How do I do this in the form?

[full code is here](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/56bdaf52094dd7b99b255a3cae458227)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the [following answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/4w051c/how_to_render_display_name_for_choice_field_in/d641ose) from reddit user roambe:

Since city is a foreign key, Django will use the __str__ (or __unicode__) method of the City model for the choice label.
This should make it start behaving like you want to (substitute for unicode if needed):

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.get_name_display()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your line `'city': forms.RadioSelect(),`, you need to define the choices for it. It should look like:

```
from blah.models import City

class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'categories', 'city']
        widgets = {'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'placeholder': 'Enter a descriptive title'}),
            'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'The article'}),
            'categories': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
            'city': forms.RadioSelect(choices=City.CITY_CHOICES),
        }
```

The radio select widget inherits from the select widget, which has a brief mention of the choices argument in the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Select

Comment: Thanks! Some other people have said to put `choices=CITY_CHOICES`, but that raises an error. This doesn’t, so that’s great. However, the output is still the same.

Comment: What about when you use {{form}}?

Comment: same thing happens, I’m afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to extend the argument a little, with a 'work-around' solution for an inherit problem.

In my situation, the returned value never changes from 'value' to 'human-r'. I believe it depends on my db-django config: on my db the field is a FK, but on Django is a simple CharField. In this way I can't define a **str** method for it without make changes to the model.
I decided, I had only 2-3 choices, to override the get_status function in order to evaluates the status and return a 'constant' output (a simply IF construct).